# Akka Remoting Failures with Amazon EC2

Tags: scala, amazon-ec2, akka, akka-remote-actor

I'm building a library with Akka actors in Scala to do some large-scale data crunching.

I'm running my code on Amazon EC2 spot instances using StarCluster. The program is unstable because the actor remoting sometimes drops:

While the code is running, nodes will disconnect one by one in a few minutes. The nodes say something like:

```
[ERROR] [07/16/2014 17:40:06.837] [slave-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [akka://slave/system/endpointManager/reliableEndpointWriter-akka.tcp%3A%2F%2Fslave%40master%3A2552-0/endpointWriter] AssociationError [akka.tcp://slave@node005:2552] -> [akka.tcp://slave@master:2552]: Error [Association failed with [akka.tcp://slave@master:2552]] [
akka.remote.EndpointAssociationException: Association failed with [akka.tcp://slave@master:2552]
Caused by: akka.remote.transport.netty.NettyTransport$$anonfun$associate$1$$anon$2: Connection refused: master
```

and

```
[WARN] [07/16/2014 17:30:05.548] [slave-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-12] [Remoting] Tried to associate with unreachable remote address [akka.tcp://slave@master:2552]. Address is now quarantined, all messages to this address will be delivered to dead letters.
```

Even though I can ping between the nodes just fine.

I've been trying to fix this; I've figured it's some configuration setting. The Akka remoting documentation even says,

> However in cloud environments, such as Amazon EC2, the value could be
>   increased to 12 in order to account for network issues that sometimes
>   occur on such platforms.

However, I've set that and beyond and still no luck in fixing the issue. Here are my current remoting configurations:

```
akka {
  actor {
    provider = "akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider"
  }
  remote {
    enabled-transports = ["akka.remote.netty.tcp"]
    netty.tcp {
      port = 2552
      # for modelling
      #send-buffer-size = 50000000b
      #receive-buffer-size = 50000000b
      #maximum-frame-size = 25000000b
      send-buffer-size = 5000000b
      receive-buffer-size = 5000000b
      maximum-frame-size = 2500000b
    }
    watch-failure-detector.threshold = 100
    acceptable-heartbeat-pause = 20s
    transport-failure-detector {
      heartbeat-interval = 4 s
      acceptable-heartbeat-pause = 20 s
    }
  }
  log-dead-letters = off
}
```

and I deploy my actors like so all from the master node:

```
val o2m = system.actorOf(Props(classOf[IntOneToMany], p), name = "o2m")
val remote = Deploy(scope = RemoteScope(Address("akka.tcp", "slave", args(i), 2552)))
val b = system.actorOf(Props(classOf[IntBoss], o2m).withDeploy(remote), name = "boss_" + i)
etc.
```

Can anyone point me to a mistake I'm making/how I can fix this problem and stop nodes from disconnecting? Alternatively, some solution of just re-launching the actors if they are disconnected also works; I don't care about dropped messages much. In fact I thought this was supposed to be easily configurable behavior but I'm finding it difficult to find the right place to look for that.

Thank you

Comment: Have you configured your Security Group to allow incoming connections on port 2552?

Comment: Not specifically, but these are StarCluster nodes talking to each other. And the actors work for a while, then fail later. Can't be a permissions issue right?

Comment: Hmmmm... no, if they are working for a while and then failing it doesn't sound like it's a network permissions issue. Have you tried telnetting to port 2552 of master from the affected node? Just to check layer by layer.

Answer (score 2):

at least the properties syntax was wrong: acceptable-heartbeat-pause should be under watch-failure-detector, (yours are at the same level). they should be like below:

```
watch-failure-detector {
  threshold = 100
  acceptable-heartbeat-pause = 20 s
}
transport-failure-detector {
  heartbeat-interval = 4 s
  acceptable-heartbeat-pause = 20 s
}
```